# How do I add multiple rows to a sql server table based on multiple checkbox selections?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, checkbox

I have two tables: `ServiceType` and `ServiceTerm`.

The tables go hand in hand with one another, and get combined into the associative table ServiceRate. One `ServiceType` can have multiple `ServiceTerms`, but not always all of them.

On my asp.net form (VB) I want to code it to where there's a way for me to add each line to the database using a checkbox to select the `ServiceTerms` that apply to the selected `ServiceType`.

I'm completely new to asp.net, and pretty new to SQL Server 2008, too.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you tried [datagrids](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/paulabraham/populatingdatagrid02092007022124AM/populatingdatagrid.aspx)?

Comment: @EmmanuelN DataGrid is pretty old technology.  The OP should probably use a `GridView` if they're going to use an ASP.NET grid control.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example I have done in one of my projects :
where chSportsList is Id for checkbox list

```
List<ListItem> list_chSportsList = new List<ListItem>();
foreach (ListItem chsli in chSportsList.Items)
{
    Guid gui2 = Guid.Parse("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000");
    try
    {
        gui2 = Guid.Parse(chsli.Value.ToString());
    }
    catch { Response.Redirect("default.aspx"); }
    db = new IRANSportEntities();
    Customer_Sports customer_Sport = new Customer_Sports();
    customer_Sport = db.Customer_Sports.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id_Customer == gui1 && x.Id_Sports == gui2);
    if (customer_Sport == null)
    {
        if (chsli.Selected == true)
        {
            db = new IRANSportEntities();
            Customer_Sports _save = new Customer_Sports() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Id_Customer = gui1, Id_Sports = gui2 };
            db.Customer_Sports.AddObject(_save);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (chsli.Selected == false)
        {
            db.Customer_Sports.DeleteObject(customer_Sport);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

    }
}
```